# Caching content of URL

Tags: java, url, caching

I have a pretty simple use case: Cache the content of a URL with correct and automatic reloading when the content on the remote side changes (for example when "last modified" changes).

How can I do that in Java?

Note: I have spring, guava and commons-lang3 on the classpath but I couldn't find any support for this. Guava supports cache eviction but there is no way to implement per-access checks.

Comment: So what you're looking for is a pretty complete http proxy in java to be embedded into an application? I agree there should be some thing like that, but I wouldn't expect it in general purpose libraries. But looking for a specialized lib might be a good idea.

Comment: For starters, I would be content with something that accepts local files :-/ Or a cache that has a "is still valid" method which I can overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [HttpClient Cache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html).

> HttpClient Cache provides an HTTP/1.1-compliant caching layer to be used with HttpClient--the Java equivalent of a browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the **checksums** of the files in database and compare it with the remote side file.

If it fails reload the file.

Comment: The HTTP/1.1 standard was introduced 1999. I hope that after 13 years, there is a more simple way to do this than reading the standard and writing a whole lot of code :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I have changed my answer :) i guess a far more older approach :)