# How does caching in the case of dynamic files/urls work?

Tags: html, caching, browser

Can someone please clarify how caching works ? Or does it entirely depend on the browser ?

```
<script type="text/script" src="/controller/getfoo"> </script>
```

is a dynamic way of serving js file where request is set as a js file from controller .

```
<script type="text/script" src="/somewhere/foo.js"> </script>
```

is the most normal way of doing it .
How does the caching work in both cases ?

In case 1 it is going to sent a HTTP request all the time ? However that is during the page load only . In case 2  browser understands the file name is mentioned explicitly and it will check if foo.js is already available locally else sents a HTTP request ?

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two from the browser's perspective. Browsers don't make decisions based on filenames.

Comment: Right so as the answer says , we have a URL ( that can be a file name or a controller name) browser sends a HTTP request to that . If it sends correct response , we are good . HTML or PDF or CSS is decided by the server . That also means tinymce.css can be given for a controllers name , its just a URL . Interesting .

Comment: Relevant question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418835/caching-content-of-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the HTTP server is configured. More specifically, in the response header, there's a key `Cache-Control:` that sets this behaviour.
If you set it in your `getfoo` action response as `Cache-Control: no-cache`, well, the first option will returns "fresh new" data every time is called.